# Node import statement can't recognize ../ prefix

Tags: javascript, node.js

I am trying to use the ES Module import with a path like `../module.js` and it gives me this error:

```
node:internal/errors:464
    ErrorCaptureStackTrace(err);
    ^

Error [ERR_MODULE_NOT_FOUND]: Cannot find module
```

Here is the structure of the folders:

```
.
├── module.js
├── index.js
├── folder
│   └── test.js
```

Also here is the import and export statements

```js
//folder/test.js
import { test } from "../module"

//module.js
export async function test(data) {
    //Do Stuff then return data
}
```

Obviously, I have changed some file names and removed the function code. Please let me know if this is a problem.

Thank you!

Comment: Try using 

import {test} from "@/module" 

instead 

import {test} from "../module"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In ECMAScript Modules, file extensions are mandatory according to the [documentation](https://nodejs.org/dist/latest-v17.x/docs/api/esm.html#mandatory-file-extensions), as well as directory indexes must be explicitly specified:

```
import { test } from "../module.js";
```

Answer (score -1):

Try using require:

```
const { test } = require('../module.js')
```

Answer (score -2):

module is already declared into nodejs, try changing the name of your file to something else.